# How to apply Cauchy-Kowalevsky Theorem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, analyticity

The Cauchy-Kowalevsky theorem is stated in my notes as:

> For the Cauchy problem:
>    $$ \begin{cases}
> u_{y}=F(x,y,u,u_{x}) \\ 
> u(x,0)=h(x) 
> \end{cases} $$
>   If $h$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $0$ and $F$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $F(0,0,h(0),h'(0))$, then there exists a unique analytic solution for the PDE in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Well, so suppose I have the problem:

$$ \begin{cases} xu_{x}+yu_{y}+u_{z}=u  \\  u(x,y,0)=h(x,y) \end{cases}$$

We have $u_{y}=\frac{u-xu_{x}-u_{z}}{y}=F(x,y,u,u_{x})$. As  $F$ is  not analytic in $(0,0,h(0),h'(0))$, we cannot apply **Cauchy-Kowalevsky** theorem, can we?

Comment: You can't do it in this way, but why not apply it to $u_z = u - xu_x-yu_y$?

Comment: @ Homegrown Tomato thanks for the response. Yes, I understand I can do it that way... But in several books I have seen the theorem stated other ways... What if I cannot solve the equation for any $u_{x_{i}}$? What does it imply for the problem provided? I mean, there is an extra condition there (Or there seems to be a condition there not stated in other books and notes) for the Cauchy Kowalevsky theorem. I understand the conditions of *being analytic*, not this one. For example for the problem $ xu_{x}+yu_{y}+zu_{z}=u $...